# Curl prevent timeout cheat

Tags: http, curl

I have an odd question I hope someone can help with.

I tried googling this, but all results for preventing curl timeouts are about the curler.

In this case, I'm the CURLEE (in other words, I have the web page being curled).

So, I have no control over what the curling server is doing. I only have control over what I feed it.

Since most of the pages being requested are complex PHP pages, they could take a while. The curling server has a standard timeout of 30 seconds, and with some scripts, this timeout is reached and I'm unable to pass the result.

Is there anyway to prevent the curling server from timing out from my end?

I was fiddling around with sending 200 ok headers and intermittent empty content, but was unsuccessful.

Here is one of my unsuccessful attempts:

```
<?php
$limit = 500;
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
flush();

$count = 0;
while ( $count < $limit ) {
        $count++;
        sleep(1);
        echo str_pad("", 1024);
        flush();
}
echo "Count = " . $count;
exit();
```

But alas, the curling server abandoned after 30 seconds.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should try HTTP Chunked transfer encoding.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

The HTTP header would look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately didn't work. The curler is still returning a timeout error after 30 seconds.
`Error: Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 16384 bytes received`
FYI: [new test script source](https://pastebin.com/qkLLpDqG)